# Issues with Event Delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use this jQuery plugin:
http://ethaizone.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/#

The fact that I load the buttons over AJAX is causing me issue. I know that i need event delegation to solve this but sadly I can't figure out how to correctly do that.

My current code is:

```
        (function($) {

        $(document).on( "click", "a[data-toggle='confirmation']", function( event ) {
            $(this).confirmation()
        });

    }(jQuery));
```

And the HTML button:

```
<a href='test' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='confirmation'>Click me</a>
```

Sadly there are some issues. If I click the button, it redirects me to the given href attribute without showing the dialog first. If I remove the href, then I need to click the button 2 times to bring up the dialog (after that once click on the same button is enough to bring it up again).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't "need" event delegation. It's merely one way to solve a problem.

Comment: Ah okay. Feel free to let me know another way to do that, as it is not working atm anyways

Comment: Your handler assignment isn't the issue. Just saying that delegation isn't actually needed. Lots of people go around saying it is though it's not.

Comment: I see. What would be another way? Just curious.

Comment: You can assign handlers directly to new elements as they're created.

Comment: How is this method called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following a hyperlink is the browser's default action for an `a` element with a `href` attribute. You need to tell the browser not to do that by calling `preventDefault`:

```
$(document).on( "click", "a[data-toggle='confirmation']", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).confirmation()
});
```

It appears that that library expects you to provide a `data-href` attribute, which is the URI to browse to if the user accepts the confirmation:

```
<a href='test' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='confirmation' data-href="/accept-url">Click me</a>
```

Comment: Okay, this does make sure that it does not redirect to the href right away but it still does not redirect to it even after clicking the confirm button. :(

Comment: I've updated the answer - the docs say you should provide a `data-href` attribute.

Comment: It says that you can provide it, otherwise it will chose the default href one. But even if I provide it, it will show it when I move over the confirm button, but if I click it, nothing happens beside the fact that it closes the tooltip.

Comment: For some reason it places a "onclick" return false on the button. How can I fix that?

Comment: I think you're misreading the docs - they say you can provide `href` as an JavaScript option to `confirmation({ /* options */ })`, or provide a `data-href` attribute in the DOM.

Comment: If it assigns an event listener like that, honestly I would avoid the library - that's a massive, hard-to-detect bug waiting to happen.

Comment: Hmm, sadly this is the only plugin I found which does exactly what I would need. I also tried it with 5 browsers and it works fine everywhere, so I am pretty sure that I just do something wrong.

Comment: The only issue now is that it adds the onclick false to the button. Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: Nevermind, he has this in the js file, no idea why. Removed it and now it works perfectly.